# How do I fix "ambiguous overload" error when overloading operator<< (templated)?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying to overload the << operator, but I get the following error:

> error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << "Test "'

..Followed by 5 billion other errors similar to:

> c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include/c++/ostream:165:7: note:
>   candidates are: ...

This comes up because I'm using cout in my main.cpp file.

Here is my code:

In BinTree.h:

```
    template <typename T>
    class BinTree{
    ...
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream&, const T&);
```

In BinTree.cpp:

```
    template <typename T>
    std::ostream& operator<< (std:: ostream& o, const T& value){
        return o << value;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: I'm not totally convinced that you've provided us with enough code to solve this problem, but the info you _have_ given us leads me to ask: Why does `operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&)` need access to `BinTree<T>`'s internals if it doesn't ever use them (or `BinTree<T>`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function has the same signature than the one already defined. This is why the compiler moans about ambigous overload. Your function tries to define a function to stream everything to a ostream. This function already exists in the standards library.

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std:: ostream& o, const T& value){
    return o << value;
}
```

What you perhaps want to do is write a function that defines how a BinTree is streamed (to everything). Please note that the stream type is templated. So if you chain the calls to the stream operator it streams the concrete type.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T& operator<< (T& o, const BinTree<U>& value){
    //Stream all the nodes in your tree....
    return o;
}
```

Comment: Um... Where exactly did you find that such function in the standard library?

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean..

```
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const BinTree<T>& v){
    typename BinTree<T>::iterator it;
    for(it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it){
                 os << *it << endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Post more code, till then see this part:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std:: ostream& o, const T& value){
    return o << value;
}
```

This is doing nothing but calling itself. It is recursive call. The `operator<<` is defined to output value of type `T`, and when you write `o<<value`, it calls itself, as the type of `value` is `T`.

Second, since this is function-template, the definition should be provided in the `.h` file, not in `.cpp` file if you expect your code working by including `.h` file.