# Define a template operator<< for iterables

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++14

I'm able to define and use:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<int> const& container)
{
    for (auto const& n : container)
        os << n << ", ";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data{0,1,2};
    std::cout << data << '\n';
}
```

([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28f98bb7b4a91829))

But the definition of that operator doesn't depend on what kind of container I use. From there, I'd like to define a templated version:

```
template<class Iterable>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Iterable const& iterable)
{
    for (auto const& n : iterable)
        os << n << ", ";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data{0,1,2};
    std::cout << data << '\n';
}
```

([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e0f8ea93f075204))

This is where my compiler gets angry and verbosily reject it:

> ```
> error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'char')
> ```

... with a lot of possible candidates.

**Why is it not legal and how could I define such an operator?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in this other StackOverflow question, [How do I fix “ambiguous overload” error when overloading operator<< (templated)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7782577/5470596)
, when defining `operator<<(std::ostream&, T)` for all `T`, you overload it for types where an existing `operator<<` exists. Hence the ambiguous call:

```
os << n << ", ";
        ^-- recursively calls itself? or calls the overload provided by the Standard Library?
```

The solution is to use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to ensure you define your overload only for iterable types. Since the definition of the [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is based on `begin` and `end`, we can use it to discriminate what is an `Iterable`:

```
template<class Iterable, class = std::void_t<decltype(begin(std::declval<Iterable>()))>>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Iterable const& iterable)
{
    for (auto const& n : iterable)
        os << n << ", ";
    return os;
}
```

([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc2327bd9b1f6449))

Now, `std::cout << data` calls your version and `std::cout << '\n'` calls the build-in overload since the substitution fails for `Iterable = char`: `begin(char)` is not defined.